# Non relational database design with SQL Server?

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework, non-relational-database

I'm currently working on developing an e-commerce website and I'm going to use C#, Entity Framework with SQL Server 2008 for this project.

The database structure is not complex, just likes Wordpress Database. I found out about non-relational database like Google BigTable, MongoDB,...but still not completely understand the advantages of this technology.

I know that SQL Server cannot be NoSQL DMS just by removing all of the relationships between tables but I still concern on this question:

If we remove all the relationships in SQL Server and working with Entity Framework, is it faster or slower or any disadavantages?

Thanks for reading and sorry for my bad English. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can easily emulate a NoSQL DB just by having only a single table with just an identity column and an XML column. I'd have to imagine it'd be slower, though.

Comment: Thanks for ur comment but I want to keep the structure ^^

Comment: I don't see a point in using an ORM if your not using a RDBMS. The advantages of something like EF is inheritance, complex types, etc - if your going to have a single table or two just use classic ADO.NET.

Comment: Just by removing the relationships, you gain **nothing** - you're neither faster, nor is it really a "NoSQL" approach. If you use SQL Server - then use it, and make the best of its relational features! Relationships and referential integrity are there **for a good reason** - use them to your advantage, don't just turn them off...

Comment: @marc_s - could not agree more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "relationships" I guess you mean Foreign Keys? Removing foreign keys has nothing to do with a database being "non-relational".

The principal reason for using foreign keys and other constraints is for data integrity. Usually constraints are the most efficient way to implement integrity rules. They can also be used by the optimiser to improve the performance of some queries. My advice to you is to design the database with the integrity constraints you need and optimise the database afterwards.